# Node mongoose move one array element into another array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I currently have a UserSchema that looks as follows:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email:  String,
    password: String,
    pendingFriends: [this],
    friends: [this]
})
```

Given a username, how would I move a record from the pendingFriends array into the friends array? This would take place in the currently logged in user's schema. This is a route I currently have for putting a friend into the pendingFriends array:

```
app.post("/addFriend", function(req, res) {
var conditions = {
    username: req.body.globalUserName,
    'pendingFriends._id': {$ne: req.user._id},
    'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id}
}
var update = {
    $addToSet: {pendingFriends: { _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, language: req.user.language, profilePicture: req.user.profilePicture}}
}

User.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, function(error, doc) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(currentTime + " - FRIEND_REQUEST_SEND_ERROR: '" + req.user.username + "' TRIED TO SEND A FRIEND REQUEST TO '" + req.body.globalUserName + "'");
    }
    else {
        console.log(currentTime + " - FRIEND_REQUEST_SENT: '" + req.user.username + "' SENT A FRIEND REQUEST TO '" + req.body.globalUserName + "'");
    }
    res.redirect("/talk");
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will help

```
var conditions = {
username: req.body.globalUserName,
'pendingFriends._id': {$eq: req.user._id},
'friends._id': {$ne: req.user._id}
}
var update = {
   $pop: {pendingFriends: { _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, language: req.user.language, profilePicture: req.user.profilePicture}},
    $addToSet: {friends: { _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, language: req.user.language, profilePicture: req.user.profilePicture}}
}
```

use this in for findandupdate query as mentioned in question.